# Complex JSON Response for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am working some portion of twitter api, and getting some JSON response using ASIHTTPREQUEST. Below is how the json representation looks like:

```
(
    {
        contributors = "<null>";
        coordinates = "<null>";
        "created_at" = "Tue Nov 29 15:48:35 +0000 2011";
        entities =         {
            hashtags =             (
            );
            media =             (
                                {
                    "display_url" = "pic.twitter.com/650E1WRY";
                    "expanded_url" = "http://twitter.com/ashu1702/status/141544088850796545/photo/1";
                    id = 141544088854990848;
                    "id_str" = 141544088854990848;
                    indices =                     (
                        22,
                        42
                    );
                    "media_url" = "http://p.twimg.com/AfbdmVBCEAAPJvT.jpg";
                    "media_url_https" = "https://p.twimg.com/AfbdmVBCEAAPJvT.jpg";
                    sizes =                     {
                        large =                         {
                            h = 279;
                            resize = fit;
                            w = 215;
                        };
                        medium =                         {
                            h = 279;
                            resize = fit;
                            w = 215;
                        };
                        small =                         {
                            h = 279;
                            resize = fit;
                            w = 215;
                        };
                        thumb =                         {
                            h = 150;
                            resize = crop;
                            w = 150;
                        };
                    };
                    type = photo;
                    url = "http://t.co/650E1WRY";
                }
            );
            urls =             (
            );
            "user_mentions" =             (
            );
        };
        favorited = 0;
        geo = "<null>";
        id = 141544088850796545;
        "id_str" = 141544088850796545;
        "in_reply_to_screen_name" = "<null>";
        "in_reply_to_status_id" = "<null>";
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str" = "<null>";
        "in_reply_to_user_id" = "<null>";
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str" = "<null>";
        place = "<null>";
        "possibly_sensitive" = 0;
        "retweet_count" = 0;
        retweeted = 0;
        source = "<a href=\"http://www.apple.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">iOS</a>";
        text = "I am in Syria @(null) http://t.co/650E1WRY";
        truncated = 0;
        user =         {
            "contributors_enabled" = 0;
            "created_at" = "Sun May 01 15:20:52 +0000 2011";
            "default_profile" = 1;
            "default_profile_image" = 1;
            description = "<null>";
            "favourites_count" = 0;
            "follow_request_sent" = "<null>";
            "followers_count" = 0;
            following = "<null>";
            "friends_count" = 5;
            "geo_enabled" = 0;
            id = 291164338;
            "id_str" = 291164338;
            "is_translator" = 0;
            lang = en;
            "listed_count" = 0;
            location = "<null>";
            name = "Ashutosh Tiwari";
            notifications = "<null>";
            "profile_background_color" = C0DEED;
            "profile_background_image_url" = "http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png";
            "profile_background_image_url_https" = "https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png";
            "profile_background_tile" = 0;
            "profile_image_url" = "http://a2.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png";
            "profile_image_url_https" = "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png";
            "profile_link_color" = 0084B4;
            "profile_sidebar_border_color" = C0DEED;
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color" = DDEEF6;
            "profile_text_color" = 333333;
            "profile_use_background_image" = 1;
            protected = 0;
            "screen_name" = ashu1702;
            "show_all_inline_media" = 0;
            "statuses_count" = 62;
            "time_zone" = "<null>";
            url = "<null>";
            "utc_offset" = "<null>";
            verified = 0;
        };
    }
)
```

My concern here is, before actually setting the entire content to data model, is there any specific way to set the  parameters to empty string?

Like there are two entities as "time_zone" = ""; and "utc_offset" = ""; Is there anyway to iterate through the json response and set @"" empty string. I don't want to validate for NSNULL feature at every key point, and it can cause my app to have some loop holes to crash at some point, therefore I just want to figure out how to iterate through such complex json to check each entity and set empty string for NSNull type class. I did tried recursive way but it only gives the list of the upper level keys not the entities within the dictionary.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure those line result in a NSNull being deserialized? They seem to be strings containing <null>, which would be fine for you, wouldn't it?

Comment: @HenriNormak I thought the same way until I started assigning it through my Data Model to UITextFields. Or maybe when I am assigning my NSDictionary in Data Model that's when it's setting it up? But doesn't makes sense. It always gives an exception of NSNull when it see's such kind of parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"<null>"` values appear to be character strings, not NSNulls.  If you want to replace the character string with `""`, you could use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfstring:withString:` to convert them en mass (as some risk of converting stuff you don't intend to).

(But to be certain, it would be good if you presented some of the raw JSON, vs the Objective-C `description` of the NSArray/NSDictionary objects which is apparently what you're showing.)

Comment: correct, I also assumed that he is showing NSObject.description's, hence my answer and the hint to test for NSNull.

Comment: @Till you are correct, I am showing the NSObject type description. The actual representation looks like "Time_Zone":null, thats just an example to be given. So basically in nsobject's representation its showing as <nsnull>. When I utilize a uitextfield as timezone.text = the json object, it gives me a nsnull exception. I thought it would be a string type, but I just don't get why it is showing such exception. Thanks

Comment: The exception is thrown because you may not assign [NSNull null] towards a UI-object as a NSString. @"" != [NSNull null];

Comment: The odd thing is that what's being printed is not `<null>`, but `"<null>"`.  But I guess it's just the "dumb" NSDictionary `description` logic that quotes anything with non-alpha characters.

Comment: Well Till and Hot Licks, I tried replacing string for json response of @"null" to @"" it works, but when I try to parse as objectofstring type to a dictionary the dictionary throws a null back. I get error like "nsnull isequaltostring unrecognized selector sent to instance" since I get to set NSNull for that, but I was just hoping to bypass it by setting empty string for null at the first place. Any reason why json responseString for parser object will be setting the dictionary to null? Thanks.

Comment: If you're getting "NSNull isEqualToString unrecognized selector" that says that the object to the left of `isEqualToString` is an NSNull, not an NSString.  You can simply place the string you're comparing to on the left and the unknown object on the right, to get a compare that will be FALSE if the unknown object is NSNull.  Or (better) use `isEqual` vs `isEqualToString` and leave the object order as is.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to do that manually. Testing against `[NSNull null]` is the way to go.

Comment: its amazing, there is no feature to actually set all the null parameter to empty string before hand. Just more expensive work.

Comment: @kforkarum note that you should always check external data excessively for type-correctnes. Otherwise you app will really be terribly fragile. This is especially true for a JSON feed.